# How can I save my object with a date in array?

Tags: angular

I want to save my object with all my attributs. And I need my createdAt for comparison in other classes. So I can't do it like a string.

```
export class LikeActivity extends BaseActivityModel {
  idLikes: [{
    _id: string;
    piinsId: string;
    createdAt: Date;
  }];

  constructor(_id: string, piinsId: string, createdAt: Date) {
    super();
    this.idLikes[_id] = _id;
    this.idLikes[piinsId] = piinsId;
    // My error it's just here
    this.idLikes[createdAt] = createdAt;
  }
}
```

My error is "Can not use 'Date' type as index type." Thank you if you have the solution

Comment: You need more context, what does BaseActivityModel like? and are you sure this is angular? isn't createdAt an ISO string coming from mongodb? you could set it as a 'string' and then have this.idLikes[createdAt] = new Date(createdAt)

Comment: You found the solution with new Date(createdAt). Everything it's ok and yes I'm in angular. You can post the solution for the point, I'll do it for you if you don't do it. Thank you!!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I've posted it as an answer for people stumbling upon this thread in the future, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because createdAt is from mongodb -- it will always be returned as a string and not an actual date object, but to work with it all you got to do is define it in your interface as `createdAt: string` and then when you define your class:

```
this.idLikes[createdAt] = new Date(createdAt);
```